# Cannot open some tables in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, innodb

Recently i get backup of my database from host in that backup i get table in .ibd,.frm,.myd format .

I placed this files in

> xampp->mysql->data->test

. Now i can open the tables in php myadmin. Now i can open some tables .But some files i can not open . When clicked it showing `932 - Table 'table.name' doesn't exist in engine` . And also i noticed in the collection column it is showing in use

Why this happen . Please help to solve

[image]

Comment: So you've transplanted database table files from one machine to another. Are you sure both machines are running compatible versions of MySQL? Can you simply copy files from one MySQL install to another and expect it to work every time?

Comment: If I were you, I'd request an SQL backup, not a table file backup.

Comment: Sorry , i know what i did is not a  good method . But this is the only thing i can do in current situation . Please tell how can i solve the issue .

Comment: This is my current situation  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244709/database-as-it-is-raw-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, your remote host machine crashed, and all they could recover was the database table files.

Now these really aren't meant to be moved, written to or read from by anything other than the very database engine that created them. Any attempt to do so is ***not guaranteed to work***. But as you're left with no alternatives, we're going to have to try anyway.
You started off well, I think, by trying to read the files into a local database engine. The problems you're having may be to do with two important differences:

1. The version of MySQL you're running locally vs. the one running remotely.
2. The Operating System locally vs. remote.

Both you can fix easily. I would get these out of the way first, to exclude them as potential sources of trouble.

So install VMware or VirtualBox on your machine, and recreate a guest VM with the same OS as the one provided by your hosting provider. Then install onto that VM the same version of MySQL that also runs on your remote host.

Also, I repeat what I said earlier: look out for an alternative to your current hosting provider to fall back on, and as long as your hosting provider can't guarantee the safety and integrity of your data, you must be prepared to make frequent backups yourself.

Comment: so i will miss data from back up ?

Comment: could you please tell step by step instruction to dump files from my local host

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is the ***remote*** host that you want a backup of, right? But regardless of whether it is the local host or the remote host with your provider, does the machine you need the dump from have MyPhpAdmin?

Comment: Cloud you please come to the chat, then i can tell you correctly

Comment: Just to be clear: a backup of a MySQL database does ***not*** consist of the table files produced by its engine. A backup of a MySQL database consists of the SQL statements necessary to recreate the entire database + contents.

Comment: For InnoDB, a `.ibd` its `.frm` file is _not_ sufficient for moving a table from one machine to another.  There is other info in `ibdata1`.

Comment: So you'd basically need to move the entire install, not just one database or a few tables?